# Typeorm Postgres map nested relationships

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I have four tables.

PASSENGER(USER_ID) > USER(AIRPORT_ID) > AIRPORT(CITY_ID) > CITY(COUNTRY_ID) > COUNTRY.

I need to take from DB PASSENGER ID, USER NAME, AIRPORT NAME, CITY NAME AND COUNTRY NAME In one level. Like this:

```
{passengerId: 1, userName: 'Test', airportName: 'TestAirport', city: 'TestCity', country: 'TestCountry'}
```

And I tried do like this.

But it returns me nested object:

```
await this.createQueryBuilder('passenger_user')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('passenger_user.user', 'user')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('user.homeAirport', 'airport')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('airport.city', 'city')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('city.country', 'country')
      .select([
        'passenger_user',
        'user',
        'airport',
        'city',
        'country'
      ])
      .where('passenger_user.email = :email', {email})
      .getOne();
```

```
{
  passenger: id,
  user: {userName: 'Test',
        airport:{
          airportName: 'TestAirport'
         ...
      }
  }
}
```